# Thin/Sinatra config/paths problem

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I have Sinatra application which I want to use Thin webserver.
I made following configs:

config/config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/session'

require 'haml'
require 'sass'

require 'myapp.rb'

Rack::Handler::Thin.run Sinatra::Application, :Port => 4567
```

config/thin.yaml:

```
--- 
environment: development
chdir: /home/proj/myapp
pid: tmp/thin.pid 
rackup: config/config.ru 
log: log/thin.log 
max_conns: 1024 
timeout: 30 
max_persistent_conns: 512 
daemonize: true
```

I am using `thin start -C config/thin.yaml` in `/home/proj/myapp` to start thin with my application

**PROBLEM:**

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - /home/proj/myapp/config/views/login.haml
```

I don't understand why it tries to look views in `/home/proj/myapp/`**config**`/views/login.haml`, when it needs to look in `/home/proj/myapp/views/login.haml`

When I am launching just: `ruby myapp.rb` everything works fine

Comment: Even if I launch Thin like `thin start -c /home/proj/myapp -C config/thin.yaml` saying Thin to `-c CHDIR` result is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in config.ru should be:

```
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Changed, re-launched, but problem still exists.

Comment: That's weird. Can you try move the config.ru at the root of your project.

Comment: Moved, it helped. Was it bug or my fault?